# HTML content not showing in mail

Tags: php, html, email

I had set up email sending in localhost and using that I can access my gmail account to send mail using php script.

```
<?php

$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "HTML Mail";
$message  = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<b>Hey! How are you today?</b>";
$message .= "<br>Regards";
$message .= "</body></html>";

$headers = "From: myemail@gmail.com\r\n";


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "<h1>MAIL SENT</h1>";
?>
```

When I send this email using this script, it gives out

```
<html><body><b>Hey! How are you today?</b><br>Regards</body></html>
```

Why html type output is not shown?

> **Hey! How are you today?**
> Regards

Like this in gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP documentation for mail():

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

If these headers are missing, the message content is interpreted as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you are missing headers to specify this is HTML content?

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```

Edit: As pointed by another answer, both headers are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for sending email with HTML body you need to specify headers. Something like this

```
//your code <br>
$headers = "From: myemail@gmail.com\r\n"; <br>
//HTML headers <br>
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; <br>
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

so after that you can send the email with html body

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

good luck